# How do I sum a vector using fold?

Tags: vector, rust

[This](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/iterators.html) Rust tutorial explains the `fold()` mechanism well, and this example code:

```
let sum = (1..4).fold(0, |sum, x| sum + x);
```

works as expected.

I'd like to run it on a vector, so based on that example, first I wrote this:

```
let sum: u32 = vec![1,2,3,4,5,6].iter().fold(0, |sum, val| sum += val);
```

which threw an error:

```
error: binary assignment operation `+=` cannot be applied to types `_` and `&u32` [E0368]
let sum = ratings.values().fold(0, |sum, val| sum += val);
                                              ^~~~~~~~~~
```

I guessed this might be a reference-related error for some reason, so I changed that to `fold(0, |sum, &val| sum += val)`, which resulted in

```
error: mismatched types:
expected `u32`,
   found `()`
```

Hm, maybe something's wrong with the closure? Using `{sum += x; sum }`, I got

```
binary assignment operation `+=` cannot be applied to types `_` and `&u32`
```

again.

After further trial and error, adding `mut` to `sum` worked:

```
let sum = vec![1,2,3,4,5,6].iter().fold(0, |mut sum, &x| {sum += x; sum});
```

Could someone explain the reason why `fold()` for vectors differs so much from the tutorial? Or is there a better way to handle this?

For reference, I'm using Rust beta, 2015-04-02.

Comment: You introduced a big difference by replacing `sum + x` by `sum += x`.

Comment: I can't believe it, how could I miss that... Thanks!

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Since Rust 1.11, you can [`sum`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.sum) the iterator directly, skipping `fold`:

```
let sum: u32 = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].iter().sum();
```

---

You've already figured out that `+=` is the problem, but I'd like to provide some more exposition.

In your case, the arguments provided to the `fold` closure are `_` and `&u32`. The first type is an not-yet-specified integer. If you change your fold call to `fold(0u32, |sum, val| sum += val)`, you'll get a slightly different message:

```
let sum: u32 = vec![1,2,3,4,5,6].iter().fold(0u32, |sum, val| sum += val);
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  |
2 |     let sum: u32 = vec![1,2,3,4,5,6].iter().fold(0u32, |sum, val| sum += val);
  |                                                                          ^^^ expected u32, found &{integer}
  |
  = note: expected type `u32`
  = note:    found type `&{integer}`
```

The result value of the binary assignment operation `+=` is `()`, the unit type. This explains the error message when you changed to `fold(0, |sum, &val| sum += val)`:

```
let mut a = 1;
let what_am_i = a += 1;
println!("{:?}", what_am_i); // => ()
```

If you change to `fold(0, |sum, &val| {sum += val ; sum})`, you then get an understandable error about immutable variables:

```
let sum: u32 = vec![1,2,3,4,5,6].iter().fold(0, |sum, &val| {sum += val; sum});
```

```
error[E0384]: re-assignment of immutable variable `sum`
 --> src/main.rs:2:66
  |
2 |     let sum: u32 = vec![1,2,3,4,5,6].iter().fold(0, |sum, &val| {sum += val; sum});
  |                                                      ---         ^^^^^^^^^^ re-assignment of immutable variable
  |                                                      |
  |                                                      first assignment to `sum`
```

From here, you *could* mark `sum` as mutable, but the correct solution is to simply fold with `sum + val`, as you discovered.

Answer (score 20):

So it turned out there was a huge difference in my code, as I wrote

```
sum += x
```

instead of

```
sum + x
```

Well, at least I hope this question helps, in case someone gets into similar situation.