# How do I compute the dot product of two Rust arrays / slices / vectors?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to find the dot product of two vectors:

```
fn main() {
    let a = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
    let b = a.clone();
    let r = a.iter().zip(b.iter()).map(|x, y| Some(x, y) => x * y).sum();
    println!("{}", r);
}
```

This fails with

```
error: expected one of `)`, `,`, `.`, `?`, or an operator, found `=>`
 --> src/main.rs:4:58
  |
4 |     let r = a.iter().zip(b.iter()).map(|x, y| Some(x, y) => x * y).sum();
  |                                                          ^^ expected one of `)`, `,`, `.`, `?`, or an operator here
```

I've also tried these, all of which failed:

```
let r = a.iter().zip(b.iter()).map(|x, y| => x * y).sum();
let r = a.iter().zip(b.iter()).map(Some(x, y) => x * y).sum();
```

What is the correct way of doing this?

[(Playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e650008c52d67f105acd2a898bf154c9)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In `map()`, you don't have to deal with the fact that the iterator returns an `Option`. This is taken care of by `map()`. You need to supply a function taking the tuple of both borrowed values. You were close with your second try, but with the wrong syntax. This is the right one:

```
a.iter().zip(b.iter()).map(|(x, y)| x * y).sum()
```

Your final program required an annotation on `r`:

```
fn main() {
    let a = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
    let b = a.clone();

    let r: i32 = a.iter().zip(b.iter()).map(|(x, y)| x * y).sum();

    println!("{}", r);
}
```

[(Playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a9496c28a87579e8e826125bfea28c25)

See also:

- [Why can't Rust infer the resulting type of Iterator::sum?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41017140/155423)
- [How do I sum a vector using fold?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29548819/155423)

---

More info on the closure passed to `map`: I have written `...map(|(x, y)| x * y)`, but for more complicated operations you would need to delimit the closure body with `{}`:

```
.map(|(x, y)| {
    do_something();
    x * y
})
```