# Why can't Rust infer the resulting type of Iterator::sum?

Tags: types, rust, type-inference

This code works:

```
fn main() {
    let a: i32 = (1i32..10).sum();
    let b = a.pow(2);
}
```

If I remove the `i32` type from `a`, then I get this error:

```
rustc 1.13.0 (2c6933acc 2016-11-07)
error: the type of this value must be known in this context
 --> <anon>:3:13
  |
5 |     let b = a.pow(2);
  |             ^^^^^^^^
```

[Run the example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=fn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20a%20%3D%20(1i32..10).sum()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20b%20%3D%20a.pow(2)%3B%0A%7D&version=stable&backtrace=0)

I would have expected that Rust turns `(1i32..10)` into an `i32` iterator and then `sum()` knows to return an `i32`. What am I missing?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40243061/1233251

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The way `sum` is defined, the return value is open-ended; more than one type can implement the trait `Sum<i32>`.  Here's an example where different types for `a` are used, both of which compile:

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
struct Summer {
    s: isize,
}

impl Summer {
    fn pow(&self, p: isize) {
        println!("pow({})", p);
    }
}

impl std::iter::Sum<i32> for Summer {
    fn sum<I>(iter: I) -> Self
    where
        I: Iterator<Item = i32>,
    {
        let mut result = 0isize;
        for v in iter {
            result += v as isize;
        }
        Summer { s: result }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a1: i32 = (1i32..10).sum();
    let a2: Summer = (1i32..10).sum();
    let b1 = a1.pow(2);
    let b2 = a2.pow(2);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=174437a2ff96bdfb5bad672cc1999e68&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Since both result types are possible, the type cannot be inferred and must be explicitly specified, either by a turbofish (`sum::<X>()`) or as the result of the expression (`let x: X = ...sum();`).

Answer (score 19):

> and then `sum()` knows to return an `i32`

This is the key missing point. While the "input" type is already known (it has to be something that implements `Iterator` in order for `sum` to even be available), the "output" type is very flexible.

Check out [`Iterator::sum`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.sum):

```
fn sum<S>(self) -> S
where
    S: Sum<Self::Item>,
```

It returns a generic type `S` which has to implement [`Sum`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Sum.html). `S` **does not** have to match `Self::Item`. Therefore, the compiler requires you to specify what 
type to sum into.

Why is this useful? Check out these two sample implementations from the standard library:

```
impl Sum<i8> for i8
impl<'a> Sum<&'a i8> for i8
```

That's right! You can sum up an iterator of `u8` **or** an iterator of `&u8`! If we didn't have this, then this code wouldn't work:

```
fn main() {
    let a: i32 = (0..5).sum();
    let b: i32 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4].iter().sum();
    assert_eq!(a, b);
}
```

[As bluss points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41017140/why-cant-rust-infer-the-resulting-type-of-iteratorsum/41019677?noredirect=1#comment69281483_41019677), we could accomplish this by having an *associated type* which would tie `u8 -> u8` and `&'a u8 -> u8`.

If we only had an associated type though, then the target sum type would always be fixed, and we'd lose flexibility. See [When is it appropriate to use an associated type versus a generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32059370/155423) for more details.

As an example, we can also implement `Sum<u8>` for our own types. Here, we sum up `u8`s, but increase the size of the type we are summing, as it's likely the sum would exceed a `u8`. This implementation is in *addition* to the existing implementations from the standard library:

```
#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
struct Points(i32);

impl std::iter::Sum<u8> for Points {
    fn sum<I>(iter: I) -> Points
    where
        I: Iterator<Item = u8>,
    {
        let mut pts = Points(0);
        for v in iter {
            pts.0 += v as i32;
        }
        pts
    }
}

fn main() {
    let total: Points = (0u8..42u8).sum();
    println!("{:?}", total);
}
```

Comment: A logical step missing I think; Just because multiple types want to sum to the same thing, doesn't mean there has to be another type parameter. It could be solved with an associated type `&'a i8 -> i8` and `i8 -> i8` and so on.

Comment: Thanks. I mean, it's not your issue, it's in the library, but since this answer was sort of going through steps to rationalize it, I wanted to point it out. Rationalizing the impl that exists is probably the road to happiness anyway ;-)

Comment: Another advantage is that `sum` can do error handling if you sum results, i.e. bail out with the first error. Same for `product`, and `collect` also does similar things.