# Why can't Rust infer the result of sum when given an explicit type of a sequence

Tags: rust

The following code is unable to deduce the type of s

```
fn main() {
    let l: Vec<u32> = vec![];
    let s = l.iter().sum();
    println!("{:?}", s);
}
```

This is motivated by something in Rust by Example https://rustbyexample.com/std_misc/threads/testcase_mapreduce.html

```
// collect each thread's intermediate results into a new Vec
let mut intermediate_sums = vec![];
for child in children {
    // collect each child thread's return-value
    let intermediate_sum = child.join().unwrap();
    intermediate_sums.push(intermediate_sum);
}

// combine all intermediate sums into a single final sum.
//
// we use the "turbofish" ::<> to provide sum() with a type hint.
//
// TODO: try without the turbofish, by instead explicitly
// specifying the type of intermediate_sums
let final_result = intermediate_sums.iter().sum::<u32>();
```

This seems to be implying that this should be possible. Or have I misinterpreted this suggestion?

N.B. I see some related ticket e.g., [Why can't Rust infer the resulting type of Iterator::sum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41017140/why-cant-rust-infer-the-resulting-type-of-iteratorsum), however in that case there is no type given for the sequence.

Comment: It's the same question as the one you linked. The type for the sequence is given in that question as well (it is `Range<i32>`).

Comment: I confirmed with the Rust by Example team that it is a typo error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This seems to be implying that this should be possible. Or have I misinterpreted this suggestion?

I think it's a misinterpretation.

```
// TODO: try without the turbofish, by instead explicitly
// specifying the type of intermediate_sums
let final_result = intermediate_sums.iter().sum::<u32>();
```

It says you can do without the turbo fish by **explicitly specifying the type**, that is by doing:

```
let final_result: u32 = intermediate_sums.iter().sum();
```

In this respect, your main function can be written as:

```
fn main() {
    let l: Vec<u32> = vec![];
    let s: u32 = l.iter().sum();
    println!("{:?}", s);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't that read "specifying the type of **intermediate_sums**", ie the array being summed, not the sum result? OP already does that

Comment: hmmm, I'm not sure. Even with **intermediate_sums** as `Vec<u32>`, the compiler still cannot infer type and gives a suggestion "consider giving `final_result` a type"