# How to call a non-generic associated function from a generic struct?

Tags: function, generics, struct, rust

I want to call a **non-generic private associated function** from a **non-generic method** of a generic struct. I can't do that because Rust cannot infer the type parameter:

```
use std::fmt::Display;

struct MyStruct<T: Display> {
    val: T,
}

impl<T: Display> MyStruct<T> {
    pub fn show(&self) {
        MyStruct::label();
        println!("{}", self.val);
    }

    fn label() {
        print!("val: ");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = 42;
    let ms = MyStruct { val: x };
    ms.show();
}
```

Compiling this code gives an error:

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
 --> src/main.rs:9:9
  |
9 |         MyStruct::label();
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type for type parameter `T`
```

Comment: `MyStruct::<T>::label();`, or just `Self::label();` See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41017140

Comment: Note that you can _also_ move the `fn label()` into another `impl` that is generic over `T` but has no bounds on `Display`, since any `MyStruct` (including those that are not `Display`) can use it.

Comment: Note that while @user2722968's advice is good, you'd _still_ have to specify a `T` to call it since the struct itself is generic. See also [Should trait bounds be duplicated in struct and impl?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49229332/155423).