# From and Into with binary std::ops: cannot infer type for type parameter `T`?

Tags: rust, type-conversion, operator-overloading, binary-operators

When I do

```rust
seq += u64::from(rhs);
```

Everything works. But I'd prefer the syntax of `rhs.into()` with that I'm currently getting,

```rust
error[E0283]: type annotations needed
  --> src/sequence.rs:50:5
   |
19 | seq += rhs.into();
   |     ^^ ---------- this method call resolves to `T`
   |     |
   |     cannot infer type for type parameter `T`
   |
   = note: cannot satisfy `_: Into<u64>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `AddAssign<_>` for `Sequence`
```

This `.into()` syntax normally works. Why doesn't type inference work on binary operators `+=` such that if the LHS only implements `AddAssign<u64>` the RHS will coerce? And moreover, aside from using `from` **what is the syntax (if possible) to provide this type information to `.into` that the compiler needs?** I've tried things like `.into::<u64>(rhs)` and that also doesn't work.

---

I am implementing `AddAssign` like this,

```rust
impl<T: Into<u64>> AddAssign<T> for Sequence {
  fn add_assign(&mut self, rhs: T) {...}
}
```

And `From` like this,

```rust
impl From<Sequence> for u64 {
  fn from(seq: Sequence)-> u64 { ... }
}
```

Comment: _what is the syntax (if possible) to provide this type information to .into that the compiler needs?_  `Into::<u64>::into(rhs)`

Comment: Oh that's nifty. I tried `.into::<u64>(rhs)` and a bunch of other premutations which didn't work. Would you be able to answer with that and perhaps explain into `Into<u64>::into(rhs)` is different syntactically from `.into::<u64>(rhs)`?

Comment: Generic type parameter belongs to trait in here not the function

Answer (score 1):

You have a double `Into` indirection, probably by mistake. Since your type already implements `AddAssign<T>` where `T: Into<u64>`, then there is no need to add `.into()` to your right-hand member. It should be expected that the implementation of `add_assign` (not provided in your example) would call `into` underneath.

```rust
seq += rhs;
```

In fact, adding it would only bring ambiguity, because then the compiler was being told to call `Into<X>::into(rhs)` on a type X which is never mentioned nor constrained anywhere. The only constraint would be `Into<u64>`, but multiple types fulfill it.

A complete example:

```
use std::ops::AddAssign;

struct Sequence;

impl<T: Into<u64>> AddAssign<T> for Sequence {
    fn add_assign(&mut self, rhs: T) {
        let value: u64 = rhs.into();
        // use value
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut x = Sequence;
    x += 6_u32;
}
```

> what is the syntax (if possible) to provide this type information to .into that the compiler needs?

Again, this is not needed. But that would be possible with the so-called [fully qualified syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#fully-qualified-syntax-for-disambiguation-calling-methods-with-the-same-name).

See also:

- [Why can't Rust infer the resulting type of Iterator::sum?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41017140)

Comment: Wow, now I feel dumb. Yeah, just leaving out the `.into` works.

In other news, you're better at this than `cargo check`.

Comment: I filed this as an improvement: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/89204

Comment: @EvanCarroll I am pretty sure that error message is fine, there can be other scenarios where you can use multiple `into`s, I thought you were trying to use it like that in the first place ^^ , please note that `Into` implementations are not transitive.