# How do I create a non-recursive calculation of factorial using iterators and ranges?

Tags: rust, iterator, non-recursive

I ran into a Rustlings exercise that keeps bugging me:

```
pub fn factorial(num: u64) -> u64 {
    // Complete this function to return factorial of num
    // Do not use:
    // - return
    // For extra fun don't use:
    // - imperative style loops (for, while)
    // - additional variables
    // For the most fun don't use:
    // - recursion
    // Execute `rustlings hint iterators4` for hints.
}
```

A hint to solution tells me...

> In an imperative language you might write a for loop to iterate
>   through multiply the values into a mutable variable. Or you might
>   write code more functionally with recursion and a match clause. But
>   you can also use ranges and iterators to solve this in rust.

I tried this approach, but I am missing something:

```
if num > 1 {
    (2..=num).map(|n| n * ( n - 1 ) ??? ).???
} else {
    1
}
```

Do I have to use something like `.take_while` instead of `if`?

Comment: Look at [`Iterator::fold`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.fold)

Comment: if num > 1 {
        (2..=num).fold(1, |acc, n| acc * n)
    } else {
        1
    }

Comment: works perfect with fold! thx for that hint

Comment: You don't even need to special case `<= 1` with this approach.

Comment: Well... That's true and I didn't even realize it... Rust is still pretty magical to me ;D

Answer (score 31):

The factorial is defined as the product of all the numbers from a starting number down to 1. We use that definition and [`Iterator::product`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.product):

```
fn factorial(num: u64) -> u64 {
    (1..=num).product()
}
```

If you look at [the implementation](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.42.0/src/libcore/iter/traits/accum.rs#L53-L57) of `Product` for the integers, you'll see that it uses [`Iterator::fold`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.fold) under the hood:

> ```
> impl Product for $a {
>     fn product<I: Iterator<Item=Self>>(iter: I) -> Self {
>         iter.fold($one, Mul::mul)
>     }
> }
> ```

You could hard-code this yourself:

```
fn factorial(num: u64) -> u64 {
    (1..=num).fold(1, |acc, v| acc * v)
}
```

See also:

- [How to sum the values in an array, slice, or Vec in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23100534/155423)
- [How do I sum a vector using fold?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29548819/155423)

Comment: WOW! How did I miss that one?? Thanx A Lot

Answer (score 3):

Although using `.product()` or `.fold()` is probably the best answer, you can also use `.for_each()`.

```rs
fn factorial(num: u64) -> u64 {
    let mut x = 1;
    (1..=num).for_each(|i| x *= i);
    x
}
```